# ProcessBuilder- Run a process on success of another process

Tags: java, batch-file, system, processbuilder

Here is what I intend to do:

1. I have a Java program through which I would like to start a Batch File.
2. While this batch file is executing, I keep a check on the output on the command prompt.
3. The moment output on the command prompt is "Build Successful", I want to finish this first process and execute another batch file, else do nothing and simply finish the first process.

I have written the code and it looks like below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Testing {

static Boolean flag = true; 

public static void main (String[] args) {

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Users/narangh/Desktop/Desktop Shortcuts/Testing.bat"); 

    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();

  //  open up standard input
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(line);
                if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL")) { 
                    System.out.println("Line found");
                    flag = true; 
                    if(flag) { 
                        ProcessBuilder startWeblogic = new ProcessBuilder("C:/bea/10.3/user_projects/domains/dev/bin/startWebLogic.cmd"); 

                                Process process1 = null;
                                try {
                                    process1 = startWeblogic.start();
                                } catch (IOException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                    } 

                }
                else if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("BUILD FAILED"))
                { 
                    System.out.println("SERVER COULDN'T BE STARTED");
                    flag = false; 
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
// the outer thread waits for the process to finish
try {
    process.waitFor();

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
 }



 }

}
```

The output of this code is as below:

```
*Some Text Here* 

[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Line found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 7 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Nov 07 15:56:15 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 48M/702M
```

But it doesn't execute the second process in case of sucess. What am I missing out in this code? 
Any kind of help will be great.

Thanks, 
Hemika.

Comment: Why would you not run:C:/Users/narangh/Desktop/Desktop Shortcuts/Testing.bat && C:/bea/10.3/user_projects/domains/dev/bin/startWebLogic.cmd

Answer (score 0):

I tried the program you wrote with below changes:
1. Added missing } at the bottom
2. Changed the batch file name to reflect a batch file I have.
The program works and it fails asking for weblogic.bat which is the desired behavior?
What is the issue?

Comment: The issue is incase it finds the text "[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL", I want it to finish this process and start another process which runs another batch file namely "weblogic.bat" but it doesn't run the second batch file.